# Minidlna doesn't refresh files

Tags: media-server

I have Minidlna installed, configured and it's working almost perfectly. Whenever I download a video file from a website using IceWeasel and video is saved to my minidlna share folder that file isn't indexed. Manual refreshing doesn't work, Minidlna stop, force-reload, restart, minidlna -R doesn't work - the file is not being indexed. The only solution is to stop minidlna, put hash (#) the path to my minidlna share path in minidlna config, restart minidlna, stop it, remove # to my minidlna share path in minidlna config file, restart and it works. It's a lot to do to make it work. I have inotify set to yes, and it's properly configured in /etc/sysctl.conf. Don't know what else I could do.

Comment: dirty workaround: add a crontab that does the force-reload and file edit, a structural fix could be to see if you run the latest stable release or just the latest git pull. This could explain unexpected behaviour.

Comment: Good idea but if someone was watching something or listening to the music of minidlna resources than that would interrupt it. I just thought a script like below could be a way round it but I don't know how to create such script: 
1. Stop minidlna, 2. Put # to the path to minidlna share in minidlna config, 3. Start minidlna, 4. Remove # to the path to minidlna share in minidlna config, 6. Start minidlna.  It might look little bit over complicated but I hope someone could help to create script for that purpose :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is something I wrote from the top of my head at work, so it might contain syntax errors etc, but this can be a dirty workaround like I have mentioned in my comment.

**Use at your own risk, it is advised to find a structural solution first**

note:*this script assumes the # is not in the config when you first start to use it, it's something rough as a proof of concept*

```
#!/bin/bash
MY_PATH="media_dir=V,/mnt/ext/Media"

service minidlna stop
sed -i s^$MY_PATH^"#$MY_PATH"^ /etc/minidlna.conf

service minidlna start
sed -i s^"#$MY_PATH"^$MY_PATH^ /etc/minidlna.conf
```

Comment: Thanks for your help - I will try to adapt it to my needs.